# Why do I get "no element found" when destroying an ember data record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got this action in one of my routes:

```
removeFromCart: function(order, fromRoute) {
  order.destroyRecord();
},
```

When the aciton occurs, I get this in ember inspector console:

```
no element found
```

The record is deleted from the API, though. However, should that message in ember console be concerning?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: are you sure that you were receiving the correct `order`? through bubbling I'm guessing, right?

Comment: @Wilfred see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I realized my API end-point for the destroy method was not returning a proper JSON response, which was causing that error.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what ws the correct data to return from the API ? I'm facing the same problem now ;)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Firefox specific error, the DELETE operation works perfectly fine on chrome without errors when returning a 204 with no content from the server.

I believe this has to do with embers caching mechanism coupled with the firefox browser in particular ([more on ember caching can be found here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/#toc_caching)).

It seems the cache could be out of sync with the server. Furthermore clicking on the link provided by the js console next to the error proves that this is the case as a 404 status and body is returned, showing that after a successful DELETE operation the ember app tries to GET a resource that no longer exists.